# x64 mov instead of push sequence

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering

So after reversing an x64 binary I found this sequence at the beginning of a function:

```
mov     [rsp+8], rbx
mov     [rsp+0x10], rbp
mov     [rsp+0x18], rsi
push    rdi
```

Now I've never really quite done this in assembly (am only experienced in x86). For me that would just be a local variable initialization.

Any idea why one would have such a code as the function prologue?

Comment: I guess this function returns an object by value and the compiler handles this by creating an object in the callers stack and callee initializes it.

Comment: @nevilad oh, that's seems interesting.. Could you develop your idea?

Comment: @nevilad: This is *Windows* x64, so the callee owns the 32 bytes above the return address, the "shadow space" ([What is the 'shadow space' in x64 assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30190132)).  So no, it's not that, and that wouldn't make sense anyway because this function doesn't know the values in the registers it's storing.

Comment: This is called **copy elision** in C++ and is available since C++11. The idea is to omit copy and move constructor calls resulting in zero-copy pass-by-value semantics. But I think @PeterCordes is right, the accessed stack is in the shadow area, so it's not copy elision.

Comment: @nevilad: Copy elision doesn't modify the asm calling convention; what changes is just logical invocation of constructors (or not).  So the asm still looks like what you'd get in C for returning a struct by value.  In normal calling conventions like x86-64, that means the caller would passes a pointer to the return-value object (as a hidden first arg), so storing the first 3 args into it would look like `mov [rcx], rdx` / `mov [rcx+8], r8` / `mov [rcx+16], r9`.  (edit: example of GCC making that asm: https://godbolt.org/z/K8djM18hj)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems reasonable to use the [shadow space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30190132/what-is-the-shadow-space-in-x64-assembly) (32 bytes above the return address) for [saving some of the call-preserved registers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268586/what-are-callee-and-caller-saved-registers/56178078#56178078), instead of using more stack space to push them all.  Without that, you'd just push any call-preserved registers you wanted to use (so you could restore them later).  Here, I guess they're restored by reloading them with `mov` right before `ret`, instead of `pop`.

(In Windows x64, RDI and RSI are call-preserved registers, unlike x86-64 System V where they're call-clobbered arg-passing registers.)

Especially if it makes stack alignment work out nicely by allowing an odd number of total pushes, if there's no `sub rsp, n` to reserve more stack space.  (That's presumably why it pushes RDI instead of saving it to `[rsp + 0x20]`.)

Comment: I think that is the case here seeing the function epilogue, however I don't quite understand what you're explaining in the last paragraph...

Comment: @Alex: Windows x64 guarantees / require 16-byte alignment of RSP *before* a `call`, so a function has to adjust RSP by `n*16 + 8` before making another `call` to maintain that alignment.  i.e. an odd number of pushes.  [Is the Microsoft Stack always aligned to 16-bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52615235).  For the same design reasons as [Why does the x86-64 / AMD64 System V ABI mandate a 16 byte stack alignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49391001)