# How system V ABI's red zone is implemented

Tags: linux, gcc, x86-64, abi, red-zone

how compiler makes sure that the red zone is not clobbered? Is there any overallocation of space?

And what factors lead to choosing 128 byte as the size of red zone?

Comment: Not clobbered *when*?  And in what sense do you imagine there might be overallocation in the context if a fixed-size space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The compiler doesn't, it just *takes advantage* of the guarantee** that space below RSP won't be *asynchronously* clobbered (e.g. by signal handlers).  Making a function call will of course synchronously clobber it.

In fact, on Linux *only* signal handlers run asynchronously in user-space code.  (The kernel stack gets interrupts: [Why can't kernel code use a Red Zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25787408/why-cant-kernel-code-use-a-red-zone/38043511#38043511))

**The kernel implements the red-zone when delivering signals to user-space.**  I think that's about it; it's really pretty easy to implement.

The other thing that's relevant is when a debugger runs a function when you do something like `print foo(123)` in GDB.  GDB will actually run that function using the stack of the current thread.  In an ABI with a red-zone, GDB (or any other debugger) has to respect it when invoking that function by doing `rsp -= 128` after saving register state to restore when the user doing `continue` or single-step.

In i386 System V, `print foo(123)` will use space right below the current ESP, stepping on whatever was below ESP.  (I think; not tested).

> And what factors lead to choosing 128 byte as the size of red zone?

A signed byte displacement in an addressing mode like `[rsp - 128]` can reach that far.  IIRC, the amd64.org mailing archive I was looking through while answering [Why does Windows64 use a different calling convention from all other OSes on x86-64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429398/why-does-windows64-use-a-different-calling-convention-from-all-other-oses-on-x86/35619528#35619528) actually included a message citing that as the reason for that specific choice.

You want it to be large enough that many simple leaf functions don't need to move RSP.  e.g. at least 16 or 32 bytes, like the 32-byte shadow space in MS's Windows x64 calling convention.

You want it to be small enough that skipping over it to invoke a signal handler doesn't need to touch huge amounts more space, like new pages.  So much less than 4kB.

A leaf function that needs more than 128 bytes of locals is probably big enough that moving RSP is a drop in the bucket.  And then the +-disp8 addressing mode benefit comes into play, giving access to a whole 256 bytes of space with compact addressing modes from `byte [rsp+127]` to `byte [rsp-128]` or in dword/qword chunks.

---

#### Further reading

Reading why it's *not* safe to use space below ESP on Windows, or Linux without a red-zone, is illuminating.

Raymond Chen's blog: [Why do we even need to define a red zone? Can’t I just use my stack for anything?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=100685)

Also my SO answer covers some of the same ground: [Is it valid to write below ESP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52258402/is-it-valid-to-write-below-esp) (but with more guesswork and less interesting Windows details than Raymond.)