# space allocated on the stack

Tags: assembly, nasm, stack-memory

[image]

Hi, I'm trying to learn assembly, I have a question. As you can see in the IDA output, we see the assembly code of a function. Why is 16 bytes allocated in this function?

`sub esp,10h` -> Even if I remove this part, the code is already working?

I have read other forum posts but not detailed enough.Can you tell me what exactly is the use of allocating 16 bytes of space?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Didn't help, we don't reuse esp so I don't understand why allocate 16 bytes

Comment: @500-InternalServerError This makes no sense in this case: The stack pointer differs by 24 bytes from the stack pointer in the calling function. So if the stack pointer was aligned to 16 bytes before, it is only aligned to 8 bytes right now. Subtracting 8 bytes would have made more sense; and 8 bytes would have been enough.

Comment: [Local Variables on the Stack](https://bob.cs.sonoma.edu/IntroCompOrg-RPi/sec-varstack.html) is a helpful read. It is discussing ARM, but the process is exactly the same in your case (other than the register names and 8 verses 16 bit alignment)

Comment: It will work most of the time in this case (because you don't use `call` or `push` or anything else that overwrites the space for your local variables, even if it's below the stack pointer).  But it could be stepped on by a debugger: see [Is it valid to write below ESP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52258402)