# Why we need stack's Red Zone?

Tags: assembly, memory, memory-management, stack-memory, red-zone

According to wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_zone_(computing)

> The red zone is a fixed-size area in a function's stack frame below
> (for a push-down stack) the current stack pointer that is reserved and
> safe to use. It is most commonly used in leaf functions (functions
> that don't call other functions) for allocating additional stack
> memory, without moving the stack pointer, which saves an instruction.

Focusing on the last sentence I don't agree at all. The fact that rsp is the end of the frame is just to make things easier on us (if we want to write assembly manually or as a type of convention). So we can do something like: - at&t syntax-

```
moveq $5, -200(%rsp)
```

without using the red zone at all, so what red zone is helpful for (It doesn't save a call as claimed)?

Comment: Please Note, writing outside rsp isn't a problem for leaf functions, and I am referring to this case.

Comment: It's not that writing below RSP is unsafe (unless you go too far, into an unmapped page), you just aren't guaranteed to read the same value you wrote.  e.g. a signal handler could clobber it.  Like in [Is it valid to write below ESP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52258402) in 32-bit code.  Also, nobody said it saves a `call` instruction; it saves a `sub $24, %rsp` / `add $24, %rsp`.

Comment: As well as the linked duplicate which explains what a red-zone gives you that you wouldn't get otherwise, also see [Why can't kernel code use a Red Zone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25787408) for another example that illustrates when there'd be a problem.

Comment: `moveq $5, -200(%rsp)` **is** using the red zone. Why do you say it isn't?

Comment: @PeterCordes didn't understand this at all: "Also, nobody said it saves a call instruction; it saves a sub $24, %rsp / add $24, %rsp"

Comment: @prl in linux red zone is 128 bytes...

Comment: You wrote "(It doesn't save a call as claimed)".  I assumed you meant a `call` instruction, i.e. saving a function call.  Other instructions that execute aren't calls.