# x64 assembly code: Can I expect a value not allocated in the stack to remain without alteration?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, stack-memory, abi

Suppose that I have these two consecutive x64 instructions (running under Windows platform):

```
ADD RSP, 8
MOV RAX, QWORD PTR [RSP - 8]
```

As you see it's the equivalent to `POP RAX`. The location of `[RSP - 8]` is not allocated anymore and I'm accessing to it!!

1. Can I expect that value at `[RSP - 8]` not to be altered by a system interrupt or Windows?

I mean, can something happen (interrupt, context switch....) between the execution of those two instructions that modified the content of `RSP - 8`, so the `MOV RAX, [RSP - 8]` will read a garbage value?

2. What if those two runs in a device driver? Does the same apply?

Comment: On Windows, no it's not *guaranteed* to be safe. (It would be safe in user-space under Linux or other non-Windows OS, since the x86-64 System V ABI guarantees a red-zone).  In user-space under Windows, there aren't many things that can user your process's stack, though.   See [Is it valid to write below ESP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52258402) -  SEH handlers are one thing.  (AFAIK, the situation for x64 Windows isn't much different from 32-bit x86, unlike for non-Windows.)  In kernel code, RSP will be used by hardware interrupts.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [Is it valid to write below ESP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52258402) - someone correct me if I'm wrong and there's some important difference or something else that makes this worth answering separately.

Comment: @PeterCordes, you are right, it's duplicated. Didn't put the correct "search words" to find it before asking. Sorry about that and thanks for the link

Comment: with `QueueUserAPC2` data below rsp can be overwritten at any time. un kernel mode - with any interrupt. so you can not except this